# How can I download a file instead of opening it in the browser (Firefox)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, download, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working with AngularJS. I want to list the files as `<a>` tag in a page. When I click it, the corresponding file should be downloaded.

I am trying withe following code,

```
<div ng-repeat="file in files">     
    <a target="_self" download="{{file.name}}" 
     ng-href="{{file.path}}/{{file.name}}">{{file.name}} </a>
</div>
```

Where **file.path** should be like this `http:///localhost/Download` then using **Apache http server** virtual host configuration I will access the file from the actual location.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost

 Alias /Download "D:/Download"
<Directory "D:/Download">
  Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The files are getting listed as expected.

But while clicking it, the url gets re-directed to that file path and showing it in the browser instead of downloading the file.

It gets downloded in `Chrome` but not working in `Firefox` (redirected to to file location and showing it in the browser)

Whats wrong with me?

Do I need to modify any settings?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
<a download="{{file.name}}" ng-href="{{file.path}}/{{file.name}}">{{file.name}}</a>
```

or just

```
<a download ng-href="{{file.path}}/{{file.name}}">{{file.name}}</a>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download for more info about the `download` attribute.

Comment: I tried with both. Still it redirects the url instead of download the file.

Comment: So, having read the documentation Stewie linked to, you'll have checked the `Content-Disposition` header. What was it set to?

Comment: @Richard Huxton: Don't mistake me. How and where can I set/update the Content-Disposition header?

Comment: Check it in your web-browser developer tools/firebug and typically set it via your Apache config and mod_headers.